# How to load image to card view from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am successfully upload my image to firebase but how can show every image in the firm of card view and make it clickable to open activity

Comment: If you google this you´ll find loots of [answers tutorial and examples](https://www.google.se/search?num=100&newwindow=1&ei=OYwRWraRLczVwAK8v4LwDg&q=How+to+load+image+to+card+view+from+firebase&oq=How+to+load+image+to+card+view+from+firebase&gs_l=psy-ab.3...930.930.0.1062.1.1.0.0.0.0.104.104.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.X1sddAtwfHI)

Answer (score 0):

You can place an ImageView inside cardview and use Glide library to fetch the image from firebase. Below is the code snippet

```
String imgUrl = "url to image in firebase";

ImageView iView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

Glide.with(mContext).load(imgUrl)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(iView);
```

There might be other ways but i used this and its fast and simple. Hope it will help you. Thank you.